# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) AJAX Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, ajax, post, server

amigos. Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario contenido en un modal hacia un controlador de Laravel. pero al hacerlo me aparece que tengo un error interno del servidor. Soy nuevo en estos temas. ¿Alguien ha tenido este tipo de problemas antes?

Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Este es el código del archivo en JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#enviar").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/profesiones_modal",
            data: {
                _token: $("#token_modal").val(),
                profesión: $("#profesion_modal").val(),
                abreviatura: $("#abreviatura_modal").val()
            },      
            success: function (response) {
                alert("thank u");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Este es el código del modal para que puedan ver los inputs:

```html
<form id="modal-create-profesion-form" class="form-signin" method="post">
        <input id="token_modal" name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="profesion_modal" name="profesión" class="form-control" placeholder="Profesión" required
                autofocus autocomplete="off">
            <label for="profesion">Profesión</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="abreviatura_modal" name="abreviatura" class="form-control" placeholder="Abreviatura"
                autofocus autocomplete="off" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]+[.]$">
            <label for="abreviatura">Abreviatura</label>
        </div>
</form>
```

Este es el grupo de rutas:

```
Route::controller(OficiosProfesiones::class)->group(function () {

Route::post('/profesiones_modal', 'save_modal');
```

});

adjunto captura del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo la duda de si en el valor 'profesión' del objeto data asi lo estas mandando o se te fue el acento. Por otro lado el error 500 hace referencia a un error en el server y no veo codigo de tu controlador de laravel seria bueno que lo adjuntaras

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, Julio. Exactamente ese fue el error que tenia y no me había dado cuenta. En el controlador tenia el nombre de otra variable. lo pude solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que entres a la carpeta **storage**, luego a la carpeta **logs**  y abras un documento que se llama `laravel.txt`, elimina todo su contenido (ahi es donde se guardan los errores) guarda el archivo y lo cierras, posteriormente haces la peticion y cuando falle abres el archivo nuevamente y te indicara cual es el error.

De esta manera yo hago `debug` cuando desarrollo en `laravel`, te dejo algunas imagenes para que veas a que me refiero y espero que te sirva.

[image: Archivo laravel.txt]

Este es un ejemplo de los errores que se guardan en el archivo `laravel.txt`

```
[2022-07-27 16:22:45] debug.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [App\Models\Valoraciones]. {"userId":4,"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [App\\Models\\Valoraciones]. at Laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException.php:35)
```

Es con lo que te puedo ayudar debido a que los errores 500 tiene diversas causa, espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, David. Pude resovler ya que en el controlador tenia mal escrita la variable que hacia match con la del formulario. Gracias por el apoyo.